# Go Gorilla Websockets ~ On ping/pong fail (user disconnct) call function?

Tags: go, websocket, ping, gorilla

I'm writing a chat program with Golang and Gorilla's Websocket toolkit.

I'm wondering if there is a way to run a function whenever a user disconnects or a ping/pong message fails. I need this to remove them from variables and such. Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The application should close the connection and cleanup variables and such when the read methods (NextReader, ReadMessage) return an error.

Use ping/pong to detect disconnects.  The [chat example](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples/chat) shows how to do this.

- [Send pings](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/a68708917c6a4f06314ab4e52493cc61359c9d42/examples/chat/conn.go#L111) on a regular interval.
- [Set read deadline](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/a68708917c6a4f06314ab4e52493cc61359c9d42/examples/chat/conn.go#L56) to a time less than next expected pong.
- [Reset the read deadline](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/a68708917c6a4f06314ab4e52493cc61359c9d42/examples/chat/conn.go#L57) when a pong is received.

If a pong goes missing, the read methods will return with the read past deadline error.

Comment: In the chat example, the frontend side seems to have nothing about ping-pong. Is it handled only on the backend side?

Comment: @anil  The front end automatically responds to PING with a PONG.  No code is required.

Comment: Would re-setting read dead line after every read alone work?

Comment: @aniztar Setting the read deadline before each read works if the application has a known upper bound for when the next message should be received at that upper bound is acceptable for detecting disconnects.